# Eclipse auto-copy via SSH from one server to another upon save, PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, ssh

I'm writing a PHP app, and our team has our servers set up so that I have to copy code onto a second server every time I edit a file.  Naturally this is against the DRY concept, and simply a monotonous chore.

When I make a change to the file, and go to refresh the webpage to see the changes, both of these servers have to be updated, or else there is a chance that I will be seeing the old version on the server that hasn't been updated yet.  So I'm copying/pasting/saving hundreds of times a day while I develop this app!

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1.  In the Remote Systems Explorer, the system type is "SSH Only."  This is the same for server 2.

I would like there to be some kind of functionality where each time I save sample.php on server 1, the same file sample.php will be automatically updated and saved with the same code on server 2.  I don't want to have to do anything else other than just save the file on server 1; after doing that I'd like for the file on server 2 to be automatically updated.

Both servers are running on nginx OS.

I've been reading a lot about this here on SE, but many of the question/answers are 5+ years old, and I wonder if there is an optimal way to do this today.  I don't have much experience with Java, but I'm happy to do this any way that will work.  Any plugin or other way would be great.

Comment: what server OS? there are a number of OS based options i can think off

Comment: I would use [deployer](https://deployer.org/), you could push to n* hosts if you wanted with 1 command. Or any type of arbitrary mundane task which saves logging into many servers at once.

Comment: Hi @nogad, thanks for asking.  We run on nginx servers.  I'll edit the post to add that.

Comment: Hi @LawrenceCherone, I've edited this post to include more information.  Do you think deployer would still work in my situation?  If so, which aspect of deployer would you recommend that I investigate?

Comment: You will want to change your flow. You should be using git or another VCS! Once in place, you would do you changes, run deployer. You would create a deployment recipe which commits your local changes to the VCS, it then logs into your servers and does a git pull. The problem with not correctly deploying code is you cant rollback. imagine you have changed/added a database column then you FTP your change.. you then have a db error, with deployer you could even migrate your local schema and import it into all the server before code changes. and when things go bad simply run `dep rollback`, pheeww

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at running  rsync over ssh, and put it on a cron to run the update on a periodic interval as you desire.

Here is an example of an rsync process I run to copy database backups (type / contents of the file are mostly irrelevant here):

```
 rsync -ar -e "ssh -l <username>" <local_path_of_files_to_watch> hostname:<target_path_where_files_land>
```

This is what my command looks like to rsync databases from a remote system that monitors radio traffic and records decoded messages to a daily log file:

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files --progress --stats -e "ssh -l stratdb" 192.168.0.23:/var/log/stratux.sqlite.*.gz /Users/stratdb/sqlite-dbs/.
```

If you want this process to run without having to define a password, you'll want to setup .ssh with shared keys to allow passwordless login from server 1 -> server 2 for this process (Ideally this is done from a user that has limited capabilities on both servers).

There are some continues deployment processes you could use that would do builds and copies and the like (e.g. Jenkins) if you need really robust and highly configurable solution...  but if you just need to brute-force copy files from one server to another with a single easy command (ad-hoc) or automagically..  I'll investigate  rsync